# Two Login Screens with different accounts on both

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, user-account, login

I have a user that was having an issue with his mac where only 1 administrative account was showing up.  He'd log in, then have to log out and could see the other two accounts (his personal account and another administrative account).

I checked filevault but his personal account was the only one enabled to use filevault, so I removed the 1st administrative account that was the only one showing up on reboot.  After removing the account (and home folder securely) we reboot the mac.

The 1st administrative account is still the only one showing up, but now once we log into this account, instead of showing the desktop, it takes us to another login screen with his personal account and the other administrative account.

What do I need to do to remove the first login screen?

I believe he is using yosemite

Answer (score 1):

The first login prompt is for File Vault and shows the administrators that can unlock the machine, the second prompt is to actually login to the device and thus can be any user including guest.

To remove the double login process you will need a single administrative login account.  This account needs to be new or the password reset using the following method:

> Settings > Security & Password > Change Password ...

Alternative is to completely remove File Vault and thus one could login to the non-administrative account.  File Vault 2 is an all or nothing affair.